# Реакция на команды Telegram бота на локальном сайте

Tags: php, laravel, telegram-bot

Доброго времени суток. Хотел сделать более-менее простенького бота, с использованием Laravel 5.3 и Telegram Bot API PHP SDK ([ссылка](https://github.com/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk)). Сам сайт держу на локалке. Документация к SDK имеется, но я никак не могу разобраться с интеграцией этого всего в Laravel. Бота зарегистрировал, даже смог получить данные своего бота (id, логин, полное имя).

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Telegram\Bot\Laravel\Facades\Telegram;

class TelegramController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $telegram = new Api(config('telegram.bot_token'));
        dd($response = $telegram->setWebhook([
            'url' => 'https://telebot.dev/<token>',
            'certificate' => '/my.pem'
        ]));
    }
}
```

А как я могу зарегистрировать простые команды типа /help, /start, чтобы бот отвечал на них. По умолчанию имеется команда /help, обработчик находится в недрах SDK, но всё равно бот на них никак не реагирует.

```
<?php

namespace Telegram\Bot\Commands;

/**
 * Class HelpCommand.
 */
class HelpCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * @var string Command Name
     */
    protected $name = 'help';

    /**
     * @var string Command Description
     */
    protected $description = 'Help command, Get a list of commands';

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function handle($arguments)
    {
        $commands = $this->telegram->getCommands();

        $text = '';
        foreach ($commands as $name => $handler) {
            $text .= sprintf('/%s - %s'.PHP_EOL, $name, $handler->getDescription());
        }

        $this->replyWithMessage(compact('text'));
    }
}
```

Третий день бьюсь... Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Как вариант можно сделать как тут http://progme.ru/php/otpravka-soobshhenij-s-sajta-v-telegram-iz-php-skripta/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Локальный сайт с web hooks работать не будет по той причине, что сервер Телеграмма до него достучаться не сможет.

Можно получать обновления вручную:

```
$updates = \Telegram::getUpdates(); // array of Update
```

**Важно:** этот метод, в отличии от `Telegram::getWebhookUpdates()` возвращает не объект `Update`, а массив объектов `Update`.

Как сделать, чтобы работало и локально и на сервере:

```
// Бот отвечает сообщением, которое получил добавляя префикс "echo: "
public function webHookAction()
{
    if (config('app.env') == 'local') {
        $updates = \Telegram::getUpdates();
    } else {
        $updates = [\Telegram::getWebhookUpdates()];
    }

    /** @var Update[] $updates */
    foreach ($updates as $update) {
        $fromChatId = $update->getMessage()->getChat()->getId();
        $receivedMessage = $update->getMessage()->getText();

        \Telegram::sendMessage([
            'chat_id' => $fromChatId,
            'parse_mode' => 'HTML',
            'text' => 'echo: <i>' . $receivedMessage . "</i>",
        ]);
    }
}
```

Если хочется, чтобы разница была еще менее заметна, настройте (*говорим о локальной разработке*) какой-нибудь `cron` на вызов роута с хуком каждые несколько секунд.

Comment: Да, и рассмотренный пример был сделан для простых текстовых сообщений без использования механизма команд

Comment: ещё можно прокинуть порты php во вне и установить сертификат Let's Encrypt и работать как с тест продакшеном

Answer (score 1):

1) Ты должен создать правильный путь

```
Route::post('/' . config('telegram.bot_token'), function (Request $request) {       
        $update = Telegram::commandsHandler(true);
        return 'ok';
});
```

2) Ну и мой пример команды старт

```
class StartCommand extends Command {

    protected $name = "start";

    /**
     * @var string Command Description
     */
    protected $description = "Команда для начала общения с ботом";

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function handle($arguments)
    {           
        $this->replyWithMessage(['text' => 'Привет я Бот, вот список команд которые вам доступны:']);

        // Посылаем статус что печатаем
        $this->replyWithChatAction(['action' => Actions::TYPING]);

        $commands = $this->getTelegram()->getCommands();

        // Строим список команд
        $response = '';
        foreach ($commands as $name => $command) {
            $response .= sprintf('/%s - %s' . PHP_EOL, $name, $command->getDescription());
        }

        //Посылаем ответ
        $this->replyWithMessage(['text' => $response]);
    }
}
```

3) И конечно же проверь, отослал ли ты сертификат, потому как без него ты послать по-моему ничего не можешь

4) Последняя проблема с IP адресом, из-за выхода с локального компа, разверни бокс на [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) и проверь! как работает, для отображения логов не забудь в настройках Laravel выставить `'log' => "errorlog"`

Comment: Большое спасибо, что откликнулся и извиняюсь, за глупые вопросы.
Сделал как ты написал, добавил в routes/web.php код и команду /start заменил на твою. Но всё равно бот не реагирует. И SSL-сертификата у меня нет. Как быть?

Comment: Создавать самоподписной, и отправлять туда, только смотри тужа нужно именно файл отправлять, а не ссылку на файл

Comment: я уже успел помучатся с этими сертификатами... Пытался сделать через Windows - но постоянно что-то не то. А хостинги, выдающие сертификаты не катят, так как мне он нужен для локалки. Нельзя ли как-то обойти это?

Comment: @MyZik А ты здесь смотрел: https://core.telegram.org/bots/self-signed, как сертификат установить ?

Comment: Спасибо большое за тык ссылкой!
Я вроде как установил сертификат, сгенерировав два файла my.pem и my.key. Теперь пытаюсь установить это всё, закинув оба файла в /public/ и немного изменил содержимое контроллера, метод index. (Обновил код в вопросе)
На что получаю ошибку: Bad Request: bad webhook: Ip is reserved

Comment: Так не сталкивался, или уже не помню но [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33378216/how-to-use-setwebhook-in-telegram-with-self-certificates-on-windows-7-and-php)  можно посмотреть, а и проверь точно ли ушел твой сертификат

Comment: Но проблема видать у тебя все же с IP адресом

Comment: А можно ли как-то с тобой связаться, через Team Viewer попробовать? Был бы очень-преочень признателен.

Comment: Можешь в скайп написать orange_adrenalin, только смысл у тебя явно порблема с IP, ты через маршрутизатор в сеть выходишь ? или напрямую?

Comment: Нет, через WiFi. Какая может быть проблема с IP?

Comment: В общем у тебя точно проблема с IP адресом или Сертификатом, попробуй выложить приложение на Heroku там по моему есть бесплатный тариф и проверь